# How to know if a genetic algorithm is working?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

It is important to benchmark your algorithm before applying it to a specific question. Otherwise, garbage in, garbage out. Having implemented a genetic algorithm (GA) with elitism, I have no idea how to test whether it works or not.

I have thought about printing out the statistics, such as mean, median, and variance, of each generation. However, they are not really strong indicators of the correctness. For example, the maximum fitness doesn't say anything, because even for random search with elitism, you have a non-decreasing maximum fitness. Mean and median do not say much either, because they may occasionally deteriorate, even if the GA is perfectly correct.

What is an effective way of testing if GA is working good?

Comment: Sorry, no answer, but: This might well suit the new http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ (but maybe someone here has an idea as well...)

Comment: I think you just have to look at the result. since it is a genetic algorithm it will find anything. if it is good enough, it probably works. now there is only the question, it works good enoght for you. if not you can think about how to improve it.

Comment: You saying "the fitness of final result does not infer anything to performance" was weird. It feels like you think the fitness function you created does not correspond to true goodness of result.

Comment: Also, you could try running it on specific sets of inputs which you know exactly what is the best answer. That way you know how good the output of algorithm is compared to the global optimal. I know it might be hard for some problem to think up an input that you know the global optimal... but saying this just in case you can.

Comment: @Billiska: Realistically, just use a math equation like `-(x-A)^2-(y-B)^2`, you know the maximum is at A,B.  See if it works it's way close to that point.

Comment: @MooingDuck  "see if it works it's way close to the origin" the key point is how do you define "it". Note that we have a population, instead of an individual, in GA. If here "it" is defined as "the best individual", random search may work as well. Hence, the best individual approaching the real solution does not imply the correctness of GA. This is exactly the point I am trying to make in this question.

Comment: @FarticlePilter: A genetic algorithm is merely an optimized random search.  Do a random search as well, and measure how much slower it approaches A,B on average.  The only better way to tell would simply be a code review.

Comment: @MooingDuck I speak in case of when you're researching a GA to solve a **specific problem**. Not testing a *generic GA*. In that case it does not makes much sense to test on other manufactured function, because your research is about that specific problem, like, GA to build an automata to play an RPG game for example.

Answer (score 3):

A great approach is that you have elitism, in that way you ensure you will never lose your best individual.

However, that doesn't mean that through the generations you will see progress. First you need to understand the GA, and best way to do that is to play around with the parameters (CROSSOVER RATE, MUTATION RATE, No. INDIVIDUAL, No. ITERATION, ELITISM VALUE) and see the outcome.

As trailmax says, visualize or print out the best individual as a function of the number of iterations. If you see that the best individual is "stuck", e.i. doesn't really show progress, try to change the parameters and see what happens. If a progress is shown (ok, this is too relative!) your algorithm works. :)

Answer (score 2):

My way of deciding if the algorithm is working was to draw a plot of fitness value over the time of execution. Something like this:

[image: The less number, the better]

*[From my question on GA](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7849/dealing-with-duplicates-in-genetic-algorithm). Y-axis is fitness level of best individual (less is better), X-axis is time or number of iterations. Ignore red line - not relevant to the question*

From the graph I could determine if my algorithm is stuck in a rut and does not improve any further.

However, I had an advantage of knowing already good solution and I could compare good solution to the result of GA execution. And that way I could tell if my GA is good enough or not. This  is not always available, but you can try solving simple sub-set of your problem yourself and compare your result with the result of GA.

Just for your note, conclusion of my thesis was that GA can give you a good starting point for other algorithms to find a better solution. And GA was not fit to find the very best solution to a complex problem with many constraints.

So you can try very hard to get a great result, but nature of GA will just not give it to you.

Comment: Love the last two sentences, so true!!! The thing that a GA does best is find the local maxima in your fitness function.  The more constraints you have on a problem, the more likely the fitness function is littered with unanticipated/unwanted local maxima.

Comment: Can't you design an algorithm to avoid the already known local maximums?

Comment: @inf3rno -- That sort of assumes that you know where the local maxima are. Given a problem with 10 constraints, your task is to determine the local maxima of a function in 10 dimensional space. GA is good for that. Once GA finds the local maxima for you, then you can examine the answers provided by GA and use that information as a "good starting point for other algorithms to find a better solution".  That was my interpretation of trailmax's answer, anyways.

Comment: Yes, but you can detect automatically that it does not improve any longer, so you can stop the actual round, log the results, use them to enhance the GA, and try again... Ye :D from my perspective it seems to be simple, but I guess it is much more complicated than I think...

Comment: @inf3rno it is quite hard problem to detect when to stop GA - many papers have been published just on that topic. And trying again with GA given a result from previous GA execution - no point. I've tried that: seeded execution of new GA with known good solutions - still ended up on the same level of fitness. But if you try again with other algorithms on a solution from GA - way to go.

Comment: I don't think plotting the best individual's fitness would help. Imagine I am plotting the best individual's fitness of _a random search_ instead of _GA_, I pretty much get a plot that has the same trend as your plot.

Answer (score 1):

Trailmax's answer was OK, but incomplete.  Generally, the GA has an optimization curve very similar the one TrailMax provided, but to know whether your GA is working well I suggest 2 things.

1. Run several tests iteratively varying your population size, mutation rate, and crossover rate.  Each problem will have different best settings for these depending on how easy/hard it is to disrupt the representation, how many local optima you have, etc. etc.
2. If you're doing better than random search your GA is somewhat effective.

Common problems with GA:
1. In a problem with many constraints a repair operator or a representation that prevents "breaking" the solution may be necessary.

1. If your mutation rate is too high you may be disrupting the search.
2. If your mutation rate is too low you may be missing important answers.
3. If your population is too small you won't be able to find great answers (premature convergence).

Comment: explanation for mutation rate:

If its too high - there will be too many diversified solutions(e.i. the parents did the crossing, the born baby was super great, but then your algorithm mutated it and it turned out to be a crap), with probability that you might loose good potential solutions. And if it is too low - you don't preserve enough diversity, which can lead to premature convergence, e.i. the new population doesn't really differ from the previous one.